# What are the different forms of substitution to prove limit of multivariable function exists?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, substitution

I watched a [great youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXkRj6MKbZs) about how to prove a limit of a multivariable function exists. It explained that one method is by substitution. For example, we can solve $$lim_{(x, y) \to 0,0} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$

By substituting with polar coordinates - namely letting $x = rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$

The youtube video mentioned that polar coordinates are not the only accepted form of substitution.

**What are other forms of substitution one can use? When do you know which form to substitute with?**

Answer (score 0):

Along the line defined by the cartesian equation $y=mx $, the limit is
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {mx^2}{|x| \sqrt {1+m^2}} $$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {m|x|}{1+m^2}=0$$

it doesn't depend on $m $ so what can you say.

Comment: so you can just substitute with...whatever? I'm still not understanding what intuition one uses for choosing what to substitute with

Comment: @Matt So the limit does not exist. It depends on the slope m.

Comment: sorry, I edited my post. I forgot a square root

Comment: @Matt It is okay now.

Answer (score 0):

If the function for which you have to compute the limit is defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then you can use spherical  coordinates.

I think you will find [this](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~wshih/mathnotes/n-D_Spherical_coordinates.pdf) useful.

It is a generalization of polar coordinates in any dimension.